# error in firefox

Tags: jquery

I've added fancybox code to my web. I've tested in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE and Opera. It works fine in all navigators unless Firefox. I don't know why, when I include this code, in Firefox, my grid images, appears outside the web.
You can see the sample I refer here http://www.tepui.cat/interiors/altells.html
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the below links that u used in ur code is broken. These files not in the actual path

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.0" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.3" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.3"></script>
```

Please do correct this and check again.. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set **#taulaImatges** to have `"display: inline"` like this in css:

   > ```
   > #taulaImatges {
   >    display: inline;
   > }
   > ```

   This fixes the FireFox layout.
2. Your scripts are not loaded at all in all the browsers, so consider
   checking your paths :)